# Rotate and Skew an element in Css3

Tags: css, transform

I have a simple div element with red background and text on it. I wish this element will have a rotation and a skew. What happens as a result of my code is that the text is rotated, not the whole div element. How can I solve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #CssElement {
            position:absolute;
            top:250px;
            left:250px;
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            background-color:red;
            -webkit-transform:skew(-15deg,-30deg)  rotate(180deg);         
            font-size:40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="CssElement">Look how I am drawn</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how the element renders on screen:

[image: Good skew but bad rotation]

Comment: Your problem description seems to say that the text rotates within the element, but the element itself does not rotate (if you use `border-color` to style specific borders then you'll see that this is not the case: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XpdR8/)). Am I misunderstanding your problem? (Also, you may have posted the wrong picture/code, because the picture you show should be `rotate(90deg)`, whereas your code says `rotate(180deg)`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the text to be affected, add another element and apply inverse of the transform: 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2BDHP/2/)

```
<div id="CssElement"><span>Look how I am drawn</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
#CssElement span {
    display: inline-block;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) skew(15deg, 30deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg) skew(15deg, 30deg);
}
```